# Proving $\frac{8 \sin(70^{\circ}) \cos^{2}(70^{\circ})}{2\sin(70^{\circ})-1}=1$

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that:

> $$\frac{8 \sin(70^{\circ}) \cos^{2}(70^{\circ})}{2\sin(70^{\circ})-1}=1$$

I don't know where to start. Obviously I want a proof without using a calculator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using
$$2\sin(70^\circ)\cos(70^\circ)=\sin(140^\circ)$$
and
$$\sin(140^\circ)\cdot\cos(70^\circ)=\frac 12(\sin(210^\circ)+\sin(70^\circ)$$
we have
$$\begin{align}\frac{8\sin(70^\circ)\cos^2(70^\circ)}{2\sin(70^\circ)-1}&=\frac{4\cdot 2\sin(70^\circ)\cos(70^\circ)\cdot \cos(70^\circ)}{2\sin(70^\circ)-1}\\\\&=\frac{4\cdot\sin(140^\circ)\cdot\cos(70^\circ)}{2\sin(70^\circ)-1}\\\\&=\frac{4\cdot\frac 12(\sin(210^\circ)+\sin(70^\circ))}{2\sin(70^\circ)-1}\\\\&=\frac{2\sin(210^\circ)+2\sin(70^\circ)}{2\sin(70^\circ)-1}\\\\&=\frac{-1+2\sin(70^\circ)}{2\sin(70^\circ)-1}\\\\&=1\end{align}$$

Comment: i think the result must be $1$

Comment: This answer is unclear. It leaves the reader guessing how you got from one line to the next. Considering the OP says "I don't know where to start", I don't think an answer like this is helpful (-1)

Comment: @Zach466920 I think it gives the OP an idea of where to start. It's not 100% clear, but that's sometimes good for homework-y problems.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I disagree. In that case, giving a hint that says "use these two properties", with links and/or stated formulas, is better than just giving a copy and paste-able answer.

Comment: @zac466920 You're certainly entitled to an opinion.  But why would you down vote before you give mathlove a chance to address your comment?  That would seem to be the civil thing to do.

Comment: @mathlove +1 for the solid answer and to neutralize the down vote from zach.

Comment: @thomasandrews I completely agree.

Comment: Please no full answers for homework !!!

Comment: @Dr.MV I took my down vote off a while ago...also "to neutralize the down vote from Zach" that comes off a bit control hypocritical, I mean it literally contradicts the previous sentence "You're certainly entitled to an opinion"...(I'll just not comment next time because I'd prefer you vote based off your own beliefs rather than to neutralize my influence).

Comment: @zach466920 Note I preceded that part of the comment with "+1 for the solid answer."  There is no "control hypocrisy."  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It's *interesting* that we can easily turn $70^\circ$ into the "special" angle $210^\circ$, so that
$$\sin 210^\circ = \sin( 3\cdot 70^\circ) \tag{$\star$}$$

The left-hand side of $(\star)$ is a known value. The right-hand side can be expressed in terms of $\sin 70^\circ$ and $\cos 70^\circ$ by means of the triple-angle formula (or by expanding $\sin(2x+x)$ and using the double-angle formulas), to get
$$\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{2} = 4\sin 70^\circ \cos^2 70^\circ - \sin 70^\circ &\quad\to\quad 2\sin 70^\circ -1 = 8\sin 70^\circ \cos^2 70^\circ \\
&\quad\to\quad 1  = \frac{8\sin 70^\circ \cos^2 70^\circ}{2\sin 70^\circ -1}\end{align}$$

(where division in the last step is justified because we *know* the denominator isn't zero).

Answer (score 2):

If you know that $\cos 3x=4\cos^3 x-3\cos x$, then apply it to $x=20^{o}$. If $w=\cos 20^{o}$, then $\cos 60^o=\frac{1}{2}=4w^3 -3w$. This is equivalent to:

$$8w(1-w^2) = 2w-1$$

But $w=\cos 20^{o}=\sin 70^{o}$ nd $1-w^2=\sin^2 20^{o}=\cos^2 70$.

So if we divide by $2w-1$ we get the result you want, assuming you can show that $w\neq \frac{1}{2}$.

(I'm working backwards, but I started with your equation and saw that the left side could be expressed better in terms of $w=\cos 20^o$. Then I saw that your equality was equivalent to $8w^3-6w-1=0$.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution which should give you an idea of where to start with such a problem..

So you want to prove $8\sin(70^\circ)\cos^2(70^\circ)=2\sin(70^\circ)-1$.
The first idea would be to eliminate the $\cos$-term which is fortunately possible by the well-known $\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x=1$.
So it is equivalent to proving
$$8\sin^3 (70^\circ)-6\sin (70^\circ)=1$$
Now, this should (or at least could) remind you of the identity $\cos 3x=4\cos^3 x-3\cos x$ and you obtain
$$8\sin^3 (70^\circ)-6\sin (70^\circ)=2(4\cos^3 (20^\circ)-3\cos (20^\circ))=2\cos 60^\circ=2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}=1$$